# Links suddenly blue?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

Links are suddenly blue. Personally, from a usability standpoint, I find this to be a significant improvement (blue is the standard link color on the internet, the dull red stands out poorly compared to black to my eyes), but it doesn’t seem to fit with the overall color scheme of the site and in any event is quite sudden and unannounced, so I suspect a bug.

Answer (score 5):

Alas, that was not intentional but rather [an oversight on my part](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263464/155160).

Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

This happens occasionally. It seems to be associated with site updates and broken profile page layouts. I'm pretty sure the link blue (and its associated "mouseover" blue, "visited link" blue, etc) is the colour used for link text in the default Stack interface, so I'm guessing this is what it looks like when a site update breaks the site-specific interface and the default bleeds through.

Regardless of whether the blue is added permanently or not, it'd be a good idea to re-visit the site design with thought for [accessibility to the visually impaired](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag). Neither the blue link colours nor the older red-brown link colours are really great for it.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange is presently working on [some major CSS updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253359/152515) for our site and a few others. (These updates are for the Stack Exchange developers' sakes and aren't supposed to affect how our site actually looks.) These blue links showed up a few weeks ago and stuck around for half an hour, and various other things have broken occasionally recently, as BESW's mentioned. The redesign recently reached the stage where they were prepared to work on RPG.SE and several other sites, so this is probably a matter of things breaking and being repaired while they rejig their CSS.

This stuff is in connection with [the profile page makeover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244238/152515) which we'll receive sometime after the CSS updates are completed.

Answer (score -1):

I actually prefer the blue color, and wouldn’t mind seeing it stay. I bring up this up because I assume it is unintended, but not really because I want things to go back. This answer provided to give a place to vote on this as a change.

Comment: I suggest "make our links blue, it is much better for reasons" is better off in its own [[tag:feature-request]].

Comment: @doppelgreener probably true

Answer (score -1):

> [Blue text](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23345578#23345578) is a bit of a vibe killer. We have this cool customized Stack look and feel. This is totally breaking that