# CSS woes: blue links, messed up user page (Are we getting an upgrade?!)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

Links have suddenly turned blue, [again](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5692/links-suddenly-blue). New question instead of bumping the old one because I can’t remove [status-completed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) from the other.

Moreover, the CSS on the user pages is messed up, floats aren’t, well, floating correctly. Probably a width that is ever-so-slightly too wide, though I haven’t specifically investigated.

[image: My user page, with messed up formatting]

All of the different blocks continue down the left column, instead of doing two columns.

Probably same [story as last time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263461/old-user-page-developing-rendering-errors/263464#263464), but just in case this *isn’t* a well-known, network-wide booboo, question. Plus, hey maybe this means we’re getting [the long-awaited overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed)!

Comment: We're probably not _quite yet_ getting an upgrade, but ["a few weeks"](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5809/whats-with-the-comic-sans-like-font-for-bold-and-italic#comment16101_5813) was a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Checked my user page in photo.SE (also pending an overhaul), floats are also broken there.

Comment: My SciFi Fantasy profile has the same problem with profile view.

Comment: @doppelgreener Baby steps! (Baby steps also involve occasional faceplants.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, looks like it’s fixed (again).

Comment: Sorry about that. We accidentally [a wrong file in another file](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267281/155160).

Comment: @AnnaLear Hehe, LESS is still *so* much better than plain CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I still support adjustment to link colors here, favoring some variation on blue. This would improve visibility and be more consistent with the web as a whole. Particularly the dull red used for already-visited<sup>1</sup> links is very easy to miss for my eyes (some difficulties with red-green).

1. <sup>Might have been not-yet-visited links; I forget and I can’t check right now with all the links blue, heh. My point is the dull one. The brighter color is OK enough; at the least, I can clearly see a link embedded in the middle of a paragraph when it’s that color.</sup>

Comment: Agree on the blue, it looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I don't personally have any problems with the blue links as they're easier to see, but the profile pages being skewed downward and whatnot is funny looking at the minimum.